# Searching six fields multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to allow users to show the number of matching rows in a `progs` database using up to 4 different parameters.

The tricky bit is that the parameters could be one of 6 fields.

I'm looking for a `genre_id` on either of the rows - `genre_id1`, `genre_id2`, `genre_id3`, `genre_id4`, `genre_id5` or `genre_id6`.

So to find the numbers of correct matches for one genre id, I use this code:

```
$total=0;
for ($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
$howmany = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as Num FROM `progs` WHERE `genre_id$i`  
='$genre_id'"),0);
$total=$total+$howmany; }
```

The above code works to show how many matches for one `genre_id`. But I then want to look for another 3 genre id's as well. So I want to show the incidents where all 4 submitted genre ids appear on either `genre_id1`, `genre_id2`, `genre_id3`, `genre_id4`, `genre_id5` or `genre_id6`.

I want to get a number of the results and show the resulting rows.

I can't get my head around how I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Database Normalization

The thing you need to ask yourself is why you structured your database, the way you did.

It would be far more sensible to have just one genre_id per row. That way you can just count the number of rows that match a certain id. Why do you have 6 genre_ids in your rows?

If you do need 6 per 'prog' then simply make a new table, called 'genres' and link it to your 'progs' table. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `progs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  <any other fields>
)

CREATE TABLE `genres` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prog_id` int(11)
  <any other fields>
)
```

Here `prog_id` refers back to the `progs` table. Now this second, far simpler, table is much easier to do queries on. It's now also possible to have just 3 genres per 'prog' or 9. This is far more flexible that just 6 similar fields in one row.

See: http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think you may be right. I inherited the database and I think your suggestion is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple options

Use a "reverse" `IN`:

```
WHERE $genre_id IN (genre_id1, genre_id2, .... genre_id6)
```

or write them out in full:

```
WHERE genre_id1 = $genre_id OR genre_id2 = $genre_id OR .... $genre_id = genre_id6
```

If you need a PER-FIELD count, then you'd need something like:

```
SELECT SUM(genre_id1 = $genre_id) AS id1_matches,
    SUM(genre_id2 = $genre_id) AS id2_matches 
    etc...
```

where mysql would take the boolean true/false of the `id = $id` tests, convert that to integer `0` and `1`, and then sum up the `1`'s.

Comment: I didnt know about the reverse in approach. Very helpful to know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to write a query that uses the `IN` operator and check that the genre_id is in the list you want, like this:

```
SELECT SUM(
    (CASE WHEN genre_id1 IN (four_genre_ids) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN genre_id2 IN (four_genre_ids) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN genre_id3 IN (four_genre_ids) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN genre_id4 IN (four_genre_ids) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN genre_id5 IN (four_genre_ids) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN genre_id6 IN (four_genre_ids) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS totalMatches
FROM myTable;
```

So, for each row this will count up the number of times you have a match by adding 1 each time a match is found. This can likely be simplified in a loop, but I am not skilled enough to simplify that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think the best solution is to tidy up my database but this IN approach is something I could use in the future. Useful to know, thanks.